# Should Logging Be Its Own Microservice in an Event-Based System?

Tags: .net, logging, microservices

I have a question about Logging with regards to Microservice architecture in an event-based system running on .NET core. Basically, there are 2 ways to go about implementing logging that I can think of:

1) Use a centralized logging tool and reference it in a NuGet package in each Microservice.
2) Implement logging as its own independent Microservice that pulls log messages off the message queue. This would also use a centralized logging tool, but only this Microservice would have a reference to the NuGet package.

Now with approach #1, the issue deals with switching out the logging package/provider. Doing so would be a costly change and would require a redeployment of all microservices.

In both approaches, the logging would benefit from using a generic logging interface (probably the .NET core ILogger interface) to abstract away the implementation details.

Approach #2 has the interesting problem of "what if the queuing of the message fails?". In this case, how would that error be logged?

I can see the benefits and drawbacks of both approaches. Which strategy has the industry standardized on, for the most part, regarding logging? I am new to Microservices and think this question may help others as well.

Comment: Consider option 3: Have each microservice deal with logging on their own in order to be independent. Using a NuGet package/service will mean less flexibility or a complex package/service having to deal with different logging requirements. By taking on a strong dependency on a service or package is probably worse than some code duplication if that is what worries you.

Answer (score -2):

My perspective on processing and how to manage it is based on what I've learned from studying manufacturing and its systems.

A microservice is what Harvard Business Review would call a "process-focus" plant, where the labor is organized by technical skill. In contrast, a "product-focus" plant dedicates labor by process and step, where each step may not require a technical skill set. As I explain in my article on decentralization, "process-focus" plants and distributed manufacturing create irreversible complexity by allowing requirements to converge. My architecture is a total revolution against the DRY model.

I mostly agree with Peter's recommendation. Each process should have its own logging operation which can be replaced, upgraded or reshaped as needed for that process regardless of the labor required to do so. However, microservices are **distributed** processes -- which seriously risk centralization complexity. The only valid central processes seem to be ones which are "mathematical" like physics or Regex, in the sense that the work they do is strictly defined (by formulas and DSL) and not shaped by business requirements. And even then, they should be integrated in the consuming process not a separate application from it.

I believe the tasks we program reflect custom jobs and are better managed by a "product-focus" plant, because each step is a user requirement and the steps do not translate into reusable "general" (central) language components. Ever seen a long-winded event handler? We're asked (mostly) to write tasks which consume APIs, not to write them.

If you read my articles on the subject and HBR's, manufacturing has also asked how to organize operations. Whereas HBR emphasizes managing each organization type separately, I emphasize organizing and integrating processes to prevent complexity and allow the programmer to easily manage the process and its operations.

**Decentralization**

http://www.powersemantics.com/p.html

**Integration**

http://www.powersemantics.com/o.html

The software industry is a bit behind me, by an industrial revolution or two.